# Key Phrase Search in String

Tags: python, sql, r, databricks

I am needing to find a count of IDs that contain certain phrases in a long string.  Normally I would use SQL like this:

```
select
  count(distinct id)
from
  table
where
  lower(string) like '%phrase 1%'
  or lower(string) like '%phrase 2%'
  or lower(string) like '%phrase 3%'
```

For smaller datasets, a query like this does not cause me any issues, but the size of my table and length of the sting field in this instance will certainly take forever.

Since I am using databricks notebooks, I'm thinking that a solution might be to use either python or R to query and filter through this dataset to get the counts I am looking for.  I am less experienced with this process, so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In R, we can build the `where` clause like this:

```r
phrases <- c("phrase 1%", "phrase 2%", "phrase 3%")
where <- paste0("(", paste(paste("lower(string) like", sQuote(phrases, FALSE)), collapse = " OR "), ")")
where
# [1] "(lower(string) like 'phrase 1%' OR lower(string) like 'phrase 2%' OR lower(string) like 'phrase 3%')"
```

which can then be added to the rest of your query fairly easily.

You may want to consider [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries) instead of hard-coding programmatic string literals into your query, where you might instead do something like:

```r
where <- paste0("(", paste(rep("lower(string) like ?", length(phrases)), collapse = " OR "), ")")
where
# [1] "(lower(string) like ? OR lower(string) like ? OR lower(string) like ?)"

res <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con,
  paste("select count(distinct id) from table where", where),
  params = as.list(phrases))
```

While not required, it does mitigate inadvertent SQL-injection (albeit not malevolent) due to ANSI string issues, programming mistakes, malformed quoted strings, etc.

The use of `?` as a marker is DBMS-dependent. For instance, Postgres uses `$1`, `$2`, ...; SQLite can use `?`, `?1`/`?2`, or `:name`; SQL Server uses `?`. In my use, ODBC-connections (when connecting on windows in R) always use `?`, not sure if it differs based on the OS or calling language or something else.